# Using data.table in R, how can I supply the entire .SD to j in addition to creating new variables?

Tags: r, data.table

In interactive sessions the use of `:=` in data.table to change by reference can be a real pain when you're just fiddling around and exploring a data set, especially when making incremental changes and spamming Ctrl+Enter. Instead of using `df[,':='(new = column)]` I would like to bring along everything in .SD and then some without altering the original data set.

I get pretty close to what I'm after with the below, except that `.SD.` is prepended to the columns designated by `.SD`.

```
data.table::as.data.table(ggplot2::mpg) -> mpg

mpg[,.(.SD, gallon_ratio = hwy/cty)]
```

How can I achieve the same result without the `.SD.` prefix appended to column names?

Comment: I tried putting in an answer that used cbind: `mpg[, cbind(.SD, gallon_ratio = hwy/cty)]` but for some reason the interface is refusing to let me post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work if you put `.SD` in `c()` instead of the list.

```
library(data.table)

mpg[,c(.SD, .(gallon_ratio = hwy/cty))]

#     manufacturer  model displ year cyl      trans drv cty hwy fl   class gallon_ratio
#  1:         audi     a4   1.8 1999   4   auto(l5)   f  18  29  p compact     1.611111
#  2:         audi     a4   1.8 1999   4 manual(m5)   f  21  29  p compact     1.380952
#  3:         audi     a4   2.0 2008   4 manual(m6)   f  20  31  p compact     1.550000
#  4:         audi     a4   2.0 2008   4   auto(av)   f  21  30  p compact     1.428571
#  5:         audi     a4   2.8 1999   6   auto(l5)   f  16  26  p compact     1.625000
 ---                                                                                  
#230:   volkswagen passat   2.0 2008   4   auto(s6)   f  19  28  p midsize     1.473684
#231:   volkswagen passat   2.0 2008   4 manual(m6)   f  21  29  p midsize     1.380952
#232:   volkswagen passat   2.8 1999   6   auto(l5)   f  16  26  p midsize     1.625000
#233:   volkswagen passat   2.8 1999   6 manual(m5)   f  18  26  p midsize     1.444444
#234:   volkswagen passat   3.6 2008   6   auto(s6)   f  17  26  p midsize     1.529412
```